# avconv: how to skip files that can't be opened in a php script

Tags: avconv

So to give some kind of background. The server has 3000 odd files. I've made a script that can sort the files and convert them into mp4 and webM.

However the main problem is that some files are corrupted, broken and throw a fatal error. I've tried a little bit of investigation into

```
$errorCheck = 'avconv -v error -i '.$videopath.'';
```

but from what I can see this displays a ton of text to the console that I can't hide easily with `exec() passthorugh()`, and this is also a pain to parse.

Is this my only option, or does someone with experience of avconv have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have fixed it. Key part is '2>&1' which gives the Warning as an actual string that can be used by the passthru.

```
               $errorCheck = 'avconv -v error -i '.$videopath.' 2>&1';

                ob_start();
                passthru($errorCheck);
                $var = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean(); 

                echo $var;
```